# Not able to start Apache Geode server

Tags: apache, geode

I have installed Apache Geode on Ubuntu 16.04 with IBMjdk support.

Even though I have set JAVA_HOME properly and gfsh is included in the PATH variable, I am not able to start the server.

locator is started but status shows as below.

```
Locator in /home/test/ApacheGeode_1.3.0_Ubuntu16.04_IBMJDK on 49326d8b12f6[10334] is currently not responding.
```

Below is the message displayed on the screen while starting Geode server.

```
gfsh>start server
Starting a Geode Server in /home/test/ApacheGeode_1.3.0_Ubuntu16.04_IBMJDK/stay-powerful-fan...
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................The Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 3. Please refer to the log file in /home/test/workspace/ApacheGeode_1.3.0_Ubuntu16.04_s390x_IBMJDK/stay-powerful-fan for full details.

scan_all_blocks describing block at 000003FFAC1338A0 (header at 000003FFAC1336A0):

First 8 bytes of bottom padding are damaged

Wrapped block size is 136, allocation number is 534

Block was allocated by MemoryPoolLargeObjects.cpp:120

Block header:

000003FFAC1336A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 16  ................

000003FFAC1336B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336E0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3C C0 00 00 03 FF AC 13 2E D0  ......<.........

000003FFAC1336F0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3B 70                          ......;p

Top padding:

000003FFAC1336F0: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF          ....8...

000003FFAC133700: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133710: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133720: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133730: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133740: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133750: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133760: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133770: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133780: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133790: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133800: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133810: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133820: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133830: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133840: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133850: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133860: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133870: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133880: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133890: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

Block contents:

000003FFAC1338A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 38 A0 E7 E7  .......x....8...

000003FFAC1338B0: 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?...............

000003FFAC1338C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133900: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133910: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133920: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

Bottom padding:

000003FFAC133920: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ........

000003FFAC133930: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133940: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133950: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133960: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133970: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133980: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133990: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A30: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A40: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A50: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A60: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A70: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A80: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A90: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AA0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AB0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AC0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AD0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AE0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AF0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF                          ....8...

scan_all_blocks describing block at 000003FFAC1338A0 (header at 000003FFAC1336A0):

First 8 bytes of bottom padding are damaged

Wrapped block size is 136, allocation number is 534

Block was allocated by MemoryPoolLargeObjects.cpp:120

Block header:

000003FFAC1336A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 16  ................

000003FFAC1336B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336E0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3C C0 00 00 03 FF AC 13 2E D0  ......<.........

000003FFAC1336F0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3B 70                          ......;p

Top padding:

000003FFAC1336F0: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF          ....8...

000003FFAC133700: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133710: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133720: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133730: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133740: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133750: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133760: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133770: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133780: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133790: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133800: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133810: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133820: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133830: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133840: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133850: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133860: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133870: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133880: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133890: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

Block contents:

000003FFAC1338A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 38 A0 E7 E7  .......x....8...

000003FFAC1338B0: 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?...............

000003FFAC1338C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133900: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133910: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133920: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

Bottom padding:

000003FFAC133920: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ........

000003FFAC133930: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133940: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133950: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133960: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133970: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133980: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133990: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1339F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A30: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A40: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A50: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A60: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A70: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A80: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A90: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AA0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AB0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AC0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AD0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AE0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AF0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF                          ....8...

scan_all_blocks describing block at 000003FFAC1338A0 (header at 000003FFAC1336A0):

First 8 bytes of bottom padding are damaged

Wrapped block size is 136, allocation number is 534

Block was allocated by MemoryPoolLargeObjects.cpp:120

Block header:

000003FFAC1336A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 16  ................

000003FFAC1336B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336E0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3C C0 00 00 03 FF AC 13 2E D0  ......<.........

000003FFAC1336F0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3B 70                          ......;p

Top padding:

000003FFAC1336F0: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF          ....8...

000003FFAC133700: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133710: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133720: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133730: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133740: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133750: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133760: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133770: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133780: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133790: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133800: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133810: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133820: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133830: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133840: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133850: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133860: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133870: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133880: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133890: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

Block contents:

000003FFAC1338A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 38 A0 E7 E7  .......x....8...

000003FFAC1338B0: 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?...............

000003FFAC1338C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133900: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133910: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC133920: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

Bottom padding:

000003FFAC133920: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00          ........

000003FFAC133930: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133940: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133950: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133960: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133970: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133980: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AC0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AD0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AE0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AF0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF                          ....8...

scan_all_blocks describing block at 000003FFAC1338A0 (header at 000003FFAC1336A0):

First 8 bytes of bottom padding are damaged

Wrapped block size is 136, allocation number is 534

Block was allocated by MemoryPoolLargeObjects.cpp:120

Block header:

000003FFAC1336A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 16  ................

000003FFAC1336B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1336E0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3C C0 00 00 03 FF AC 13 2E D0  ......<.........

000003FFAC1336F0: 00 00 03 FF AC 13 3B 70                          ......;p

Top padding:

000003FFAC1336F0: -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF          ....8...

000003FFAC133700: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133710: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...


000003FFAC133770: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133780: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133790: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337A0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337B0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337C0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337D0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337E0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC1337F0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133800: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133810: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133820: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133830: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133840: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133850: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133860: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133870: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133880: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133890: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

Block contents:

000003FFAC1338A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 00 00 00 00 38 A0 E7 E7  .......x....8...

000003FFAC1338B0: 3F F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ?...............


000003FFAC1338E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

000003FFAC1338F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................


000003FFAC133A60: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A70: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A80: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133A90: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AA0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AB0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AC0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AD0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AE0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133AF0: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B00: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B10: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF  ....8.......8...

000003FFAC133B20: DE AD AC 13 38 A0 BE EF                          ....8...

Memory checker statistics:

Total blocks allocated = 64633 ( = most recent allocationNumber)

Total blocks freed = 60214

Total bytes allocated = 64905372

Total bytes freed = 23574308

Total unknown blocks ignored = 0

High water blocks allocated = 4699

High water bytes allocated = 41341402

Largest block ever allocated = size 2097152, allocation number 1890

Failed allocation attempts = 0

Memory error(s) discovered, calling exit(3)
```

Please let me know if there is any way to resolve this issue and to start server successfully.

Comment: Have you tried using OpenJDK? or HotSpot from Oracle? Geode is not tested on IBM jdk.

Comment: Yesterday I have cheked it on X8.
I am able to start the server when I build it on X86 with openjdk ,
Getting the issue with both jdks on S390X architecture.

Comment: It says in your crash dump: `The Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 3. Please refer to the log file in /home/test/workspace/ApacheGeode_1.3.0_Ubuntu16.04_s390x_IBMJDK/stay-powerful-fan for full details.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend restarting the computer/server you are using to start the server. That usually fixes it. If not, then clear pid files, and shutdown locators properly, before attempting to start a server again.

It may help to name a properties file with properties properly configured as shown below:

```
start server --cache-xml-file=..\config\cache.xml --name=NameOfServer --server-bind-address= (ip address) --properties-file=..\config\gemfire.properties --log-level=info
```

Reading logs is vital for Apache Geode. It can be very fustrating to go through the logs, but it always helps in the end. If the logs aren't helpful, then increase the level to `--log-level=info`